# unix_timestamp is behaving incorrect for Hive

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

I have below 2 Insert queries in single HQL, where I am inserting few fields from table "Final_table_temp" to Final_table1 & Final_table2. Both target table have exact same structure.

```
insert into Final_table1
PARTITION(event_date,service_id)
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.0'),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as event_date,
service_id 
from Final_table_temp;

insert into Final_table2
PARTITION(event_date,service_id)
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.0'),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as event_date,
service_id 
from Final_table_temp;
```

event_timestamp value in Final_table_temp:

```
2017-10-26 22
```

event_timestamp value in Final_table1:

```
2017-10-26 22:00:00.000
```

event_timestamp value in Final_table2:

```
2017-10-26 21:00:00.000
```

Please help me understand why it is changing the value for table2. It should be as same as table1 as their is no change in query & source is same too?

---

```
hive> desc extended Final_table1;
OK
event_timestamp         timestamp
event_date              date
service_id              int

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

event_date              date
service_id              int

Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:Final_table1, dbName:rwdb, owner:hdfs, createTime:1496391931, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:event_timestamp, type:timestamp, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:event_date, type:date, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:service_id, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://R333:8020/user/hive/warehouse/rwdb.db/Final_table1, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, parameters:{field.delim=,, serialization.format=,}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:event_date, type:date, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:service_id, type:int, comment:null)], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1496391931}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)

=======================================================
hive> desc extended Final_table2;
OK
event_timestamp         timestamp
event_date              date
service_id              int

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

event_date              date
service_id              int

Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:Final_table2, dbName:rwdb, owner:hdfs, createTime:1509000492, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:event_timestamp, type:timestamp, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:event_date, type:date, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:service_id, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://R333:8020/user/hive/warehouse/rwdb.db/Final_table2, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, parameters:{field.delim=,, serialization.format=,}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:event_date, type:date, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:service_id, type:int, comment:null)], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1509000492}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

Comment: are your tables in the same timezone?

Comment: Yes Both are in same timezone & in same Hive schema.

Comment: what is the output from DESCRIBE EXTENDED TABLEX?

Comment: Added Desc of both tables in Question itself at end. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.0' with 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'

Comment: How does it will change the hour part?

Comment: try with from_utc_timestamp instead of from_unixtime